# Adding slash at the end of image url shows homepage content on WP+Nginx-fpm

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I've got a strange problem with my wordpress site with nginx+php-fpm. When i add slash at the end of any image url like this
`https://site.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/10341941.jpg/`
i get my homepage content with lates posts with pagination... Moreover by deleting any symbol after domain-name keeping slash at the end of url i still can see my homepage without 404 errors. But when i cut that slash all images opens normaly and i get my "not found" page how it should be.

WP runs on KVM VPS Debian Stretch with nginx+php-fpm. And strange thing is that on my virtualbox test-servers with same configs i don't see such problem.
Configs are absolutely standart:

```
server_name site.ru;

root /var/www/site;
index index.html index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

}

location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    access_log off; # Disable logging
# Allow client browsers to cache files for a long period of time
    expires max;

}
```

I checked log files hoping to find out how this happening and i see that nginx have no problem with it. It just says: 200 ok, let me show you the homepage!
`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [28/Aug/2019:21:40:44 +0300] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2016/05/10341941.jpg/ HTTP/1.1" 200 11614 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36"`

Any suggestions? I understand that it's some strange case and if can't find the origins of it maybe you can tell me how to redirect to non-slash image urls...